# React Router V6 Re-renders on Route Change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

When I navigate back and forth between routes, React Router re-renders memoized routes causing `useEffect(() => [])` to re-run and data to re-fetch. I'd like to prevent that and instead keep existing routes around but hidden in the dom. I'm struggling with "how" though.

The following is sample code for the problem:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path={"/"} element={<MemoizedRouteA />} />
        <Route path={"/b"} element={<MemoizedRouteB />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

function RouteA() {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  useEffect(() => {
    alert("Render Router A");
  }, []);

  return (
      <button onClick={() => { navigate('/b') }}>Go to B</button>
  );
};

const MemoizedRouteA = React.memo(RouteA)

function RouteB() {
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  useEffect(() => {
    alert("Render Router B");
  }, []);

  return (
    <button onClick={() => { navigate('/') }}>Go to A</button>
  );
}

const MemoizedRouteB = React.memo(RouteB)
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-hertz-w9qoip?file=/src/App.js

With the above code, you'll see that the "alert" code is called whenever you tap a button or use the browser back button.

With there being so many changes of React Router over the years I'm struggling to find a solution for this.

Comment: learn to use react-query package, it'll handle all the memoization for you. We can handle and scale the big application using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I navigate back and forth between routes, React Router re-renders
> memoized routes causing `useEffect(() => [])` to re-run and data to
> re-fetch. I'd like to prevent that and instead keep existing routes
> around but hidden in the dom. I'm struggling with "how" though.

Long story short, you can't. React components rerender for one of three reasons:

1. Local component state is updated.
2. Passed prop values are updated.
3. The parent/ancestor component updates.

The reason using the `memo` HOC doesn't work here though is because the `Routes` component only matches and renders a single `Route` component's `element` prop at-a-time. Navigating from `"/"` to `"/b"` necessarily unmounts `MemoizedRouteA` and mounts `MemoizedRouteB`, and vice versa when navigating in reverse. This is exactly how RRD is intended to work. This is how the React component lifecycle is intended to work. Memoizing a component output can't do anything for when a component is being mounted/unmounted.

If what you are really trying to minimize/reduce/avoid is duplicate asynchronous calls and data fetching/refetching upon component mounting then what I'd suggest here is to apply the [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) pattern and move the state and `useEffect` call into a parent/ancestor.

Here's a trivial example using an `Outlet` component and its provided context, but the state could be provided by any other means such as a regular React context or Redux.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Routes,
  Outlet,
  useNavigate,
  useOutletContext
} from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(setUsers);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<Outlet context={{ users }} />}>
          <Route path={"/"} element={<RouteA />} />
          <Route path={"/b"} element={<RouteB />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

function RouteA() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => navigate("/b")}>Go to B</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function RouteB() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { users } = useOutletContext();

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => navigate("/")}>Go to A</button>
      <ul>
        {users.map((user) => (
          <li key={user.id}>
            {user.name} : {user.email}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-router-v6-re-renders-on-route-change]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response @Drew Reese. I'll mark it as correct but what I'm really looking for is something more like react-router-cache-route for v6. Each route is loading a feed of data from GraphQL using relay, and I'd like to keep it around in the DOM so that Relay's pagination cursors don't become out of sync when navigating back/forth in the browser history (which happens when using Relay's store-and-network fetch policy).

Looks like I'll need to see if Apollo works more consistently.

Comment: @LukeRhodes I see. I've not much of any experience with Apollo/GraphQL, but based on my experience with Redux and Redux-ToolKit Query I think it's preferable to keep the "Query" part of my code caching responses de-coupled from other logical aspects of apps like routing/navigation. It's the components rendered on routes that make/handle the data requests, and the "API" code handles caching responses. Different tools for different-ish use cases. 